# Convert timestamp in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a column of strings with values like:

```
"Wed Apr 11 15:14:45 GMT+03:00 2018"
```

I want to convert it to date in a format: `dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss`.

I have used `as.Date()` but it returned me an error:

> Error in `charToDate(x)` :    character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

Tried `anytime` function, it returns `NA`.

Please advise what should I do to convert it to the format I need?

Comment: `format` is for output, not parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *could* have just used `strptime` on your timestamp data, except that it is in the wrong format.  `strptime` does not take a timezone string as input, and also your numerical timezone has a colon in it.  In the short script below, I generate a timestamp which `strptime` can handle.

```
x <- "Wed Apr 11 15:14:45 GMT+03:00 2018"
y <- gsub("(.*)[A-Z]{3}([+-]\\d{2}):(\\d{2})(.*)", "\\1\\2\\3\\4", x)
y
tz <- gsub(".*([A-Z]{3}).*", "\\1", x)
tz
output <- strptime(y, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz)
output
strftime(output, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz)

[1] "Wed Apr 11 15:14:45 +0300 2018"
[1] "GMT"
[1] "2018-04-11 12:14:45 GMT"
[1] "11/04/2018 12:14:45"
```

### Demo

**Late edit:** I just saw that you also want to generate a custom timestamp output.  You may use another call to `strftime` to handle this.

The general workflow for problems like this (in R, databases, etc.) is to first parse the text to date/timestamp, then take that date object and render it back to a string using a different mask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great solution, I am trying to understand your regex in the second line.
Anyway, very simple and genius!

Comment: The first call to `gsub` removes `GMT` and the colon, leaving you with a timestamp which `strptime` can parse.  The second call to `gsub` extracts `GMT`, which `strptime` expects as a separate parameter, rather than embedded in the timestamp.

Comment: You have left me with no words, you are a real professional, thank you so so much!
It's my pleasure to get an answer from a professional like you!

Comment: @steves Thanks, but make no mistake about who the [all time king of R is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun).

Comment: I know, akrun is a professional, can you share linkedin profile? I would like to add you.

Comment: p.s what is the {3} for?

Comment: `[A-Z]{3}` matches the timezone string.

Comment: Just one small clarification, given "13:33:31" string, how to convert it to time?

Comment: @steves Please open a new question for this.  This has little relation to what you asked, and what was answered.  Stack Overflow's format is not an ongoing blog.